# Wrong datetime value for now() function

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a question. I'm writing a program in springu and jpa / hibernate. database which i use is PostgreSQL. I have simple table with 2 column: first with type "timestamp with time zone" and second with type "timestamp without time zone". In my model those column have "LocalDateTime" type. I use nativeQuery from JpaRepository like this:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO public.tempor(id, date1, date2) VALUES (2, now(), now());", nativeQuery = true)
void saveTransaction();
```

After inserting this to database first column have correct value from datebase datetime, but second is set as my localhost datetime. Why and how to solve this problem? Thanks for helps.

Comment: Exactly what you want to be stored in the second `date2` column ?

Comment: The database datetime when inserting new record, not localhost datetime.

Comment: `timestamp with time zone` != `timestamp without time zone`. Rather then repeat the docs here, I suggest you go to [Datetime types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) and read section *8.5.1.3. Time Stamps*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for example:

```
INSERT into tempor (id,date1) 
VALUES (1, current_timestamp);
```

second option, you can make the default value for your column as now():

```
alter table tempor alter date1 set default now();
```